# Java How to create a UTC and add few ms to the same UTC object

Tags: java, utc

```
static String createUTCTime()
{
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    f.setCalendar(cal);

    return f.format(new Date());
}
```

essentially what I would like to do below

```
Calendar objectX = createUTCTime();
//2012-Nov-27 18:35:40

x.addMS(10);
//2012-Nov-27 18:35:50
```

How do you handle UTC times to manipulate them?

Comment: Do you want a *string* (for display) or a *Date/Calendar* (for further manipulation)? They are, well, different things.

Comment: Date or Calender Object - which ever is more appropriate. Not String

Comment: So then what is `f.format(..)` supposed to do? Get rid of it and you'll be a good bit of the way to a solution (or rather, you won't be further away).

Comment: Is `addMS(10)` suppose to add 10 seconds or 10 milliseconds? Look at the example output, it differes by 10 seconds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *really* unclear what you're trying to do - but if you're trying to create an object to work with further, you shouldn't be converting it into a string representation, which is what `SimpleDateFormat.format` does.

The Java API for working with dates and times is pretty broken, to be honest - you'd be much better off with [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net). For example:

```
DateTime x = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
x = x.plusMillis(10);
```

Joda Time provides plenty of *immutable* types for dates and times, which are significantly better for readability than the mutable `Calendar` and `Date` types. Additionally, it supports a lot more types to represent different kinds of values.

Really, avoid java.util.Date/Calendar like the plague :)

Comment: Upon solving the initial problem, which is more appropriate to use Calender or Date/DateTime ?

Comment: @stackoverflow: It entirely depends on what you want to represent. If it's just a timestamp - an instant in time - then `Date` is appropriate. If it's with an associated calendar system and time zone, then use `Calendar`.

Comment: static String createUTCTime()
 {
  DateTime x = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
  
  return x.plusMillis(100).toString("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 }                       ----executing this code returns the same time. everytime the method is called. Any Idea why this side effect is happening?

Answer (score 4):

`Date` is just a point in time, it doesn't hold any time zone information. If you want to work with time zones and dates, you need `Calendar`:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.add(Calendar.SECONDS, 10);
```

Now the tricky part, you cannot *just* convert it to `Date` (`cal.getTime()`) as it will loose time zone (but will still represent the same point-in-time). What you should do is create a SimpleDateFormat` configured to use UTC.

On the other hand if you only need seconds or milliseconds, `Date` is fine. Just remember to **format it** in correct time zone. But you shouldn't use `Date` for hours and everything above (assumption that hour is 3600000 milliseconds is sometimes wrong due to leap seconds, DST, etc.)

Comment: The question asks for a few *milliseconds*; does Calendar support this granularity? (If so, it might be useful to update the code.)

Comment: @pst: not sure, but looking at the example (`18:35:40` vs. `18:35:50`) it seems like OP actually wants seconds (?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 10);

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    f.setTimeZone(cal.getTimeZone());
    System.out.println(f.format(cal.getTime()));
```

getTime provide Date object which do not have any information about timeZone. By Date object can display the date in GMT(toGMTString()) and local time zone(toLocalString()).

This code will provide you time in UTC, in the required format.

Comment: I would need to string to look like this format 2012-Nov-27 18:35:40